# Is hi-fi a proper English word?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, sentence-choice

This hotel or pub is hi-fi ?
Is that a correct sentence ?
What are other good words one can use for a good quality pubs/clubs ?

Comment: If someone said a hotel or pub was "hi-fi" I would probably think they were not a native speaker, and wonder if they meant that the place had a good sound system. I would ask if that is what they meant.

Comment: "Hi-Fi" doesn't mean "high quality", but "high fidelity" meaning the sound played back is true to the sound recorded. Fidelity is not a concept usually associated with hotels or pubs, so it doesn't make sense.
The question would be if you can talk about your "hi-fi husband"

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - honestly I'd think they are talking about wi-fi, but are mixing up the terms. I've never heard of anyone caring about the sound system of a hotel.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

"Hi-fi" is a real word, in the sense that it has been used and recorded in dictionaries for many years.  But it means a "high-quality record player" (or cd player etc).  Typically one with a separate amplifier and speakers.  It is short for "high fidelity".

So you can't talk about a "hi-fi hotel" (unless you mean a hotel whose rooms are equipped with record players)

You have already answered your own question:  You can say "Good quality hotel". Or you could use any of the hundreds of other adjectives with positive meanings: "A great/comfortable/luxury/friendly/superior hotel"

There is also the star systems for grading hotel facilties. A luxury hotel could be a "five star hotel", and this is used both strictly (To mean the hotel has been graded by an independent travel organisation) and informally to mean "luxury".

Comment: These days, not many people aged under about 50 would use the 'hi-fi' to talk about a good quality sound system.

Comment: But even fewer people would talk about "hi-fi" to mean a good quality hotel!

Comment: No, because they probably know that 'fi' is short for 'fidelity' which is a meaningless concept when applied to hotels and pubs.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey On the contrary, some such places are known for supporting infidelity

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen - So a "hi fi" hotel is one that checks that couples checking into a single-bed room really are in a committed, monogamous relationship (er, with each other)? **:-D**

Comment: I agree with the _conclusion_ here, but I think your first paragraph only really captures the _etymology_ of "hi-fi", not the meaning that would be understood by current English speakers. In current common usage, I would class "hi-fi" as exclusively a noun, and referring broadly to any standalone non-portable music player (i.e. not just a PC with speakers or a phone dock). The phrase "hi-fi hotel" sounds wrong to me not because of any expansion to "high fidelity", but simply because I would not expect "hi-fi" to be used as an adjective.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey because they haven't made a good quality sound system in the last 50 years, dammit! \*shakes cane\* More seriously, *hi-fi* is certainly in use, but nowadays it's more to describe a dedicated stereo system (as opposed to eg. a boombox) rather than to make a statement about quality.

Answer (score 11):

This question seems to be about slang, which is *highly* dependent on location and demographics. "Hi-fi" sounds ridiculous to me in this context, but I get what's intended and I imagine somebody somewhere probably does say this.

There are dozens if not hundreds of more "correct" (non-slang) choices like "good, great, fantastic, fabulous, wonderful, classy." Many of these do have subtle connotations which also tend to vary from region to region. Without knowing more about the nuances you want to convey, and the location and audience to whom you want to convey them, it's impossible to suggest a single word.

Comment: Fabulous sounded good. But then I checkt it on dictionary, surprisingly it means `extraordinarily large` . But it said `informally - very good` wonderful. So is it that we can't use fabulous to mean wonderful formally ?

Comment: @pensee I'm not sure what dictionary you looked at, but I can't think of any way that "fabulous" means "large". It's origin is "fable", a story used to teach, so was originally "like something you'd read about it in a story", but it is more often used now just to mean "very good". As for whether it's "formal" or "informal", that isn't a simple "yes" or "no"; it is less formal than some words, more formal than others. It's not rude, and it would be widely understood.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure they didn't mean Wi-Fi? It would be normal to ask if a hotel or pub was Wi-Fi (means you can connect your device to their broadband.

Comment: "does this hotel or pub have Wi-Fi ?" would be normal while "This hotel or pub is Wi-Fi ?"   would not.     Good thought - its easy to mis-hear similar words, a potential mondegreen in speech.

Comment: hi-fi？ Wi-fi,right？Lmao.

Comment: My friend was really puzzled when he thought I asked him for a Wi-Five ;))

Comment: @gonefishin'again. What is Wi-Five? Btw, Wi-Fi is the abbreviation of Wi-Fidelity as you already may know it.

Comment: It's another mondegreen, continuing the wordplay. BTW Wi-Fi was never officially an abbreviation for "wireless fidelity", that's a myth. They used it in early advertising & confused the whole world. There's the dry history on wikipedia or more interesting from https://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/entry/why-called-wi-fi_l_5cace3f7e4b01bf960065841

Comment: @gonefishin'again. Thanks. You tried to mean "High Five". Sorry:).

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the accepted answer, but since in my native language "hi-fi" can be colloquially used to mean either high quality or expensive and obsessed over insignificant details, I feel like proposing another answer.

"High-end" has similar connotations when talking about audio equipment, but can be used to describe any product or service.

Comment: High-end, or you could go with high-class, high-quality, high-priced (one hopes that a high-priced hotel is also high-quality, but not necessarily guaranteed), you could even go with "high-falutin'" if you want to sound derisive about it.

Comment: Those are fine choices too, but don't have the reference to a specific form of snobbery.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers have explained why it is not correct to describe a hotel or pub as "hi-fi," but none have suggested the adjective that I hear most often in casual speech (American English, Southwestern region):

"Is this a nice hotel/pub?" or "Is this hotel/pub nice?"

Definition 2 at [Merriam-Webster Learner's Dictionary](https://learnersdictionary.com/definition/nice):

> attractive or of good quality
>
> - nice restaurants
> - a nice car/house